# How can I merge two trees which satisfy the heap order?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, tree, heap

Is it possible to merge two trees that satisfy the heap order in time O(m+n+1)? While m and n are the height of the input trees.

```
Example 

Input:
   10              8
     \
      9 
Output: (Can be any one of them)
   10               10             10          10
     \             /  \           /  \        /  
      9           9    8         8    9      9
     /                                      /
    8                                      8
```

Comment: Just to note that not all input/output trees are heaps. I suppose that is intended.

Comment: Yes, the trees are not all heaps, but the values satisfy the heap-order property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this can be done in O( + ), on the condition that the output tree is allowed to share nodes with the input trees.

#### Algorithm

Given two root nodes `a` and `b`:

0. If both `a` and `b` are null, return null (base case)
1. If one of them is null, select the other one. Otherwise select the node with the greater value. Let's assume that `a` is that selected node.
2. Create a new node `x` with the same value as `a` has.
3. Perform recursion for merging `a.left` and `b`. Attach the merged result to `x.left`
4. Assign the unaltered `a.right` reference to `x.right`
5. return `x`

As at each level of the recursion we reduced the height of one of the trees in subject, the recursion depth will be at most the sum of the heights of both input trees, from which follows the given time complexity.

The choice for merging either `a.left` or `a.right` in step 3 is arbitrary. You could make that random.

#### Example implementation

Here is a rough implementation in JavaScript. When you run this snippet, the following two trees are merged:

```
        10              8
      /   \            / \
     4     9          7   6
    / \   / \              \
   3   1 2   5              0
```

```js
class Node {
    constructor(value, left=null, right=null) {
        this.value = value;
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }
    
    toString() {
        return (this.right ? this.right.toString().replace(/^/gm, "  ") + "\n" : "")
             + this.value
             + (this.left ? "\n" + this.left.toString().replace(/^/gm, "  ") : ""); 
    }
}

function merge(a, b) {
    if (a == null && b == null) return null;
    if (a == null || (b != null && b.value > a.value)) { 
        return new Node(b.value, merge(a, b.left), b.right);
    }
    return new Node(a.value, a.left, merge(b, a.right));
}

// Example
let a = new Node(10, 
    new Node(4, 
        new Node(3), 
        new Node(1)
    ), 
    new Node(9, 
        new Node(2), 
        new Node(5)
    )
);

let b = new Node(8, 
    new Node(7), 
    new Node(6, 
        null, 
        new Node(0)
    )
);

console.log("a:");
console.log(a.toString());
console.log("b:");
console.log(b.toString());
console.log("merged:");
console.log(merge(a, b).toString());
```

This snippet has a very basic print function -- it prints the trees rotated 90° with the root at the left side. There are no lines connecting the nodes (you'll have to imagine them), just indentation.

The example will produce this tree:

```
        10
      /   \
     4     9
    / \   / \
   3   1 8   5
        / \
       7   6
          / \
         2   0
```

Note: You mentioned O( +  + 1), but that additional constant is irrelevant: O( +  + 1) = O( + ).

Comment: This looks like a great solution, but notice that the OP defined m and n to be the *heights of the input trees rather than their sizes in terms of number of nodes, which I think is why they were asking whether O(n+m) is possible (because O(N+M) with N and M being number of nodes is trivial - just put all the nodes from both trees in an array and build a new heap). But anyway, you showed what they were asking for!

Comment: Oh, yes, missed that! Updated my use of  and  accordingly.